# When I added HttpPost attribute my app can not find the correct route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, httprequest, http-status-code-405

I used `ASP.NET 6` to develop A Web Application . I'm faced with some strange error .When I add an `HttpPost` attribute on action methods, the routing system fails to find the specific view. I added custom routing and also configured the routing system in `Program.cs` file . However, I still get http response `405` error . When I change the http request to `GET` every things work fine. Can anyone help me with this matter?

Comment: Could you  add some code showing what you did so far ?

Comment: @Jackdaw Not strictly true, there is no "default" as such, there is a convention in how the framework decides the method. For example, if you name the method "Post", then it will likely become a POST action.

Comment: @DavidG: The rule you described is true only for ASP.NET WEB API. The ASP.NET MVC has different routing system.

Comment: @Jackdaw In .NET 6 there is no distinction between API controllers and web controllers.

Answer (score 0):

> Wehn I add HttpPost attribute on action methods , the routing system
> failed to find the specific view  However , I still get http request
> 405 error . When I change http reguest to get every things work fine

I guess you excute the HttpPost method by url request. The url request, which is a HTTP GET command. So, your app got an HTTP GET command but your method wants to accept an HTTP POST method. That's why it gets http request 405 error.

You can  excute Get method firstly, then call the Post method.
From the below code you can see in the HttpPost method you can find the specific view.

```
 public IActionResult Index()
 { 
        //return View();
     return Indexpost();
 }

[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Indexpost()
 {
        return View("Privacy");
 }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @baabak Aghaei , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thank you very much.